# Powershell replace - how to avoid linebreaks at 80 chars

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command

In a batch file I need to change, within a file, all instances of ##token## (just my own placeholder) with the value of a variable from earlier in the script (%tokenvar%), and output the result to a file. From an answer on here I came up with calling powershell:

`type file.json|powershell -Command "$input|ForEach-Object{ $_ -replace \"##token##\", \"%tokenvar%\" }" > file.2.json`

The problem is that the resultant file is wrapped at 80 chars which I need it not to be!

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you try piping to `Out-String` and use the `-Width <int>` parameter?

Comment: get an error: Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter Encoding'. The argument "filepath" does not belong to the set " unicode,utf7,utf8,utf32,ascii,bigendianunicode,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute.Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.

Comment: as you'll note, I tried using Out-File because using Out-String then redirecting the output gave the same 80 char cropping.

Comment: Did you pipe the output from `-replace` to Out-String? This works for me `"foo bar" -replace "bar", "baz" | out-string -width 120`

Comment: ah - found the issue redirecting to file *outside* the powershell part. once I put it *inside* all is well.   type file.json|powershell -Command "$input|ForEach-Object{ $_ -replace \"##token##\", \"%tokenvar%\" } | Out-String -width 300 > file.2.json"

Comment: Actually ended up with:  -Command "$input|ForEach-Object{ $_ -replace \"##token##\", \"%tokenvar%\" } | Out-File -width 500 -encoding \"Default\" -filepath file.2.json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Out-String` in this case as `Out-File` has a `Width` parameter as well:

```
... | Out-File File.2.json -Width 300"
```

Just make sure the `| Out-File ...` is part of the PowerShell command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the redirection operator in PowerShell (>) will turn into Out-File with a width of 80 characters.  You can use Out-File with an arbitrarily large width (I prefer 10k), or pipe to Set-Content (which will be slower).  You can also assign the result into a variable, and use [IO.File]::WriteAllText to perform the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly in your Batch file with no need of Powershell:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.json) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   echo !line:##token##=%tokenvar%!
   endlocal
)
```

This Batch file assume that there is not empty lines in `file.json` and that the value of `%tokenvar%` have not special Batch characters. These two points may be fixed, if needed.